Usage of next-intl APIs in Server Components currently opts into dynamic rendering during build in not-found page
Description
When I run yarn build, I get this error:

Error: Usage of next-intl APIs in Server Components currently opts into dynamic rendering. 
This limitation will eventually be lifted, but as a stopgap solution, you can use the `unstable_setRequestLocale` API to enable static rendering


Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /_not-found/page: /_not-found

As the doc suggests, I have 2 not-found files:

app/[locale]/not-found.tsx
 app/not-found.tsx

I think the error comes from this:
// app/[locale]/layout.tsx
export const generateStaticParams = () => {
  return ["en"].map((locale: string) => ({ locale }));
};

Reproduction URL
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/tiavina-mika/next-intl-bug-repro-app-router
Reproduction description
Steps to reproduce:

Open reproduction
Open terminal
Run yarn build
See error in the console

Expected behaviour
The build should be ended successfully
